# facebook linter not recognizing meta tags

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I have a website with OpenGraph tags that facebook's linter is not recognizing.  The output is [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.naaly.com/exp_view/4155).

Strangely, it gives an error that og:url is missing, but further down, in the "Raw Open Graph Document Information", it does seem to have picked up the og:url correctly.  What gives?

Answer (score 1):

The Linter (now called Debugger I believe) has had known issues several times in the past, and has been reported to Facebook numerous times as well. I had the exact same issue on a page of mine, even when I tried creating a blank page with just the OG tags in the header. For me it randomly started working after.

There is one thing to check though, if you just have the OG tags you also need this instead of the normal  tag.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

It tells the browser how to use the OG tags properly since they use some non-standard code.